# I need to create a two list of words in python and i need to compare both and return common words

Tags: python

I need to create  two list as given below in python 
a = ['my','name','Green','Dev']
b = ['Green','White']

Now I need to compare both the list and print the common Words

Output Should be 
Green 
can anyone give me complete code with libraries to import.
Thanks

Comment: You have to try something yourself first. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for word in a:
    if word in b:
        print(word + "\n)
```

If you are using python 2.7 the print command should be `print word + "\n"`(i.e. w/o the parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['my','name','Green','Dev'] 
b = ['Green','White']
common = set(a) & set(b)

for x in common:
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['my','name','Green','Dev'] 
b = ['Green','White']

common = [ item for item in a if item in b ]
```